# Programming appointments in vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a simple question, how can I make my program understand that between variable A and variable B there is a time interval and I cannot add any processes there? How can I create a variable that represents the interval between A and B?

Comment: This currently makes no sense - please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Your Question ist really clear, but i think [this will help you](http://www.classanytime.com/mis333k/sjdatetime.html) (You have to take the difference between Value A and B (for example ValB - ValA))

Comment: Yes, so basically, I needed to declare 2 more variables that said where the start limit and the end limit of the processes started, also I declared a 3rd variable that could check of the upperlimit(lets say < 0:55 , maximum appointed time) or lower limit(= or > than 0) were being affected by the new entry time interval, lets say (20:00-30:00), if one of those are affected then add nothing, but if there's time available(time doesn't conflicts) then add the appointment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two questions. The second question as to creating a interval between two values is simple.

```
Interval = B – A
```

The above will thus result in the difference between the two variables and the resulting value will be in time units if the above 3 variables are Date/Time variables. (a date type variable can hold both date + time values).

As for the first question, you are looking for a basic collision.

A collision occurs when:

```
RequestStartDate <= EndDate 
and 
RequestEndDate >= StartDate
```

The above is thus a rather simply query, but if any collision occurs, the above will return records. At that point you simply don't allow the booking or the addition of the row to the table. In other words, since we NEVER allow booking with a collision, then the above simple query and logic statement will work for us. The above will find ANY over lap that exists.

It should be pointed out that the above works for a Date, a time, a number, or BETTER is a Date/Time value which is likely appropriate to your question. It is logical to assume that not only a time collision is desired, but one based on a given date (else time collisions would occur over many dates). The the above logic works EVEN in the case if the above values are Time values without the Date component part. In Access a Date variable holds both date + time, and if you are dealing with time only collisions, then the date part is a zero value. As noted, it is un-likely that you are dealing with a time only value without a given date.

The above simple query will thus find a collision and thus code logic can be used to prevent such a collisions. A sample VBA to achieve the above would thus be:

```
dim strWhere                        as string 
dim dtRequeestStartDate      as date 
dim dtRequestEndDate         as date 


dtRequestStartDate = inputbox("Enter start Date") 
dtRequestEndDate = inputbox("Enter end date") 


strWhere="#" & format(dtRequestStartDate,"mm/­dd/yyyy") & "# <= EndDate" & _ 
   " and #" & format(dtRequestEndDate,"mm/dd­/yyyy") & "#  >= StartDate" 


if dcount("*","tableBooking",strW­here) > 0 then
    msgbox "a collision exits, sorry, you can’t book"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so basically, I needed to declare 2 more variables that said where the start limit and the end limit of the processes started, also I declared a 3rd variable that could check of the upperlimit(lets say < 0:55 , maximum appointed time) or lower limit(= or > than 0) were being affected by the new entry time interval, lets say (20:00-30:00), if one of those are affected then add nothing, but if there's time available(time doesn't conflicts) then add the appointment.